# CSLA Loading list by ForeignKey in LoadData

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, foreign-keys, csla

I'm working with the MVVM pattern in C#. I have got a PlaceChild, PlaceChildList class and a Manage class which got the PlaceChildList in it. PlaceChild has a ForeignKey of ManageID.

I want in the "LoadProperty" method in the Manage class to fill the PlaceChildList with PlaceChild which has the foreign key of ManageID. I know there is a Special way to handle with foreignkeys but I couldn't find anything.

Short:
Classes -->

Manage

PlaceChild

PlaceChildList

Manage contains PlaceChildList which I want to fill with PlaceChild objects which have the ForeignKey of Manage.

Tables -->

Manage

Place (ForeignKey = ManageID)

```
    private void LoadData(Data.Manage data)
    {
        using (BypassPropertyChecks)
        {
            this.ID = data.ID;
            this.Name = data.Name;

            // this.PlaceChildListdata = .... get data by foreign key this.ID
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your question how to implement the DataPortal_Fetch code to retrieve the object data, or the DataPortal_Insert/Update code to save the object data?

Comment: the Manage class needs to retrieve all objects of PlaceChild wich got the right ForeignKey.i hoped there is something like a "get all data by foreign key" -Function :P

Answer (score 0):

As you are probably aware, CSLA doesn't implement your data access code, you do that.

The data portal does help orchestrate loading your objects with data though. I'm assuming you are using encapsulated invocation (DataPortal_XYZ), not factory implementation in the data portal.

(and I'm assuming you've read the 'Using CSLA 4' ebook, or something comparable over the years)

The data portal has a child object concept. So in your root object's DataPortal_Fetch method (which I assume is calling your LoadData method as shown in your post), you can call DataPortal.FetchChild to fetch each child.

The FetchChild method accepts a params array, allowing you to pass in whatever parameters are necessary to load each child object with data.

In the case of a collection, the parent object (the list class) normally invokes the DAL to get back all the data for the collection, then loops through that data calling FetchChild to create and load each child object. The specific row of data for that child is passed as a parameter.

There are a lot of examples of this in the Samples folder in the CSLA installer download. And the 'Using CSLA 4: Data Access' ebook covers all of this in a lot of detail.